# Quick way to get the contents of a MemoryStream as an ASCII string

Tags: c#, string, .net-4.0, arrays, memorystream

I have a JSON string in a MemoryStream. I am using the following code to get it out as an ASCII string:

```
MemoryStream memstream = new MemoryStream(); 
/* Write a JSON string to memstream here */

byte[] jsonBytes = new byte[memstream.Length];
memstream.Read(jsonBytes, 0, (int)memstream.Length);

string jsonString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(jsonBytes);
```

What is a shorter/shortest way to do this?

Comment: I tried both methods - Darin and liho1eye. Both worked well. I wish I can mark both as answer. I feel bad about marking just one as answer :| But upvoting both :)

Comment: Is there any reason to encode the JSON string into bytes, then decoding it again? You might want to consider using a StringWriter or a StringBuilder instead.

Comment: When I wanted to read from memstream, I used the Read() method for some reason and one of the overloads showed it wrote to byte arrays. So I used one. This is basically the first time I am dealing with MemoryStream class so I didn't know what was best. I just went one step at a time.

Comment: @Senthil: You are missing the point. It's when you write the JSON string to the memory stream that you encode it into bytes. If you use a class that uses character data as backing instead of byte data, you don't have to encode and decode the data, which also elliminates any problem you might have with the encoding.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the whole thing. Where and what classes should I use in order to avoid encoding/decoding?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You could use the [ToArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.toarray.aspx) method:

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    /* Write a JSON string to stream here */

    string jsonString = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(stream.ToArray());
}
```

Answer (score 6):

`new StreamReader(memstream, Encoding.ASCII).ReadToEnd()`

Comment: This will return a blank stream if the stream has been previously read to the end. To fix, prefix with "bodyStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);" or simply "memstream.Position=0".