# debugging data in memorystream using Quick Watch window

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2013, memorystream

The Text Visualizer via which I am trying to inspect data turns out to be empty in spite of data being previewed in the Quick Watch window.

Below I've described what I was up to...

I've tried to create a local variable via the Immediate Window:

[image]

I tried to view the stuff in the Quick Watch Window as follows:

[image]

To summarize: I've seeked the stream to the beginning. Tried to view the variable in the Quick Watch window; but executed a ReadToEnd() on it in order to view the data stored on memory stream. But trying to view this in the text visualizer; it is empty...why?

Answer (score 4):

Old question, but popular on google it seems, so [here's an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3542249/1605873): `System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myMemoryStream.ToArray())`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the better option here is to store the output of that function to some variable (created via immediate window), and then view that variable in the quick watch...